# How to change and set up dvc config file so can manage the weights file?

Tags: config, dvc

Im currently managing  the weight file by dvc. This is the dvc file:

```
outs:
- md5: b2c80e73090cae013eef778308faf8fc
  size: 202055043
  path: checkpoint_1.pth.tar
```

So I would like to create a dvc config file so that when it's necessary to change the weight file then I change the dvc config file. My current config yaml file for the weights is like

```
...
robot_perception_detector:
    ros__parameters:
      weights: /home/ros2/foxy/src/robot_pkg/data/model_weights/checkpoint_1.pth.tar
 ....
```

Any help and advice how this config file should looks like so that works in both cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for [Templating](https://dvc.org/doc/user-guide/project-structure/dvcyaml-files#templating). The very first example templates an output file:

`params.yaml`:

```yaml
models:
  us:
    threshold: 10
    filename: 'model-us.hdf5'
```

`dvc.yaml`:

```yaml
stages:
  build-us:
    cmd: >-
      python train.py
      --thresh ${models.us.threshold}
      --out ${models.us.filename}
    outs:
      - ${models.us.filename}:
          cache: true
```

Comment: hmm, I'm not familiar with ROS, but if it can run Python and DVC it should be fine - DVC is not platform of framework specific. It was designed to be agnostic. In this sense to you think about it as a Makefile.

Comment: @Bob9710 yes, if you experience some ROS + DVC specific problems I would describe them either here or in a separate question. If this one answers your specific question on templating path, I would keep it. Your call.

Comment: So in my case the dvc.yaml file will be:                                                           stages:
  build-us:
    cmd: >-
      python train.py
      --thresh ${robot_perception_detector. ros__parameters.n_class}                   
      --out ${robot_perception_detector. ros__parameters. weights}
    outs:
      - ${robot_perception_detector. ros__parameters. weights}:
          cache: true

Comment: You can either change it in the `params.yaml` file or using `-S` when you run `dvc exp run`.

Comment: `build-us` - no need to use exactly the same stage name (it's just an example). Also `--thresh` was a specific param for that example. Besides that it looks about right to me.